# Trim functions that uses an array of strings instead of array of char

Tags: .net, string, trim

This is similar to a recent [question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170909/trim-string-from-end-of-string-in-net-why-is-this-missing) but now I'm curious about a true replacement for the string trim functions which would remove "any" occurance of my string from the end(s). Further, to make it parrot the functionality of the base Trim(), have it accept an array of strings to trim.

Any existing implementations of this out there? I'd guess some .NET utility library would have this in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create extension methods to do this. Create your overloads and then do what you want. Plenty of ways to do it like regex or standard string functions like substring

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
  public string Trim(this string input, string remove) 
  {
     //..Do your work here
  }

  public string TrimStart(this string input, string remove) 
  {
     //..Do your work here
  }

  public string TrimEnd(this string input, string remove) 
  {
     //..Do your work here
  }

}
```