# Is there a better way to remove a trailing part of string in .NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, string

For removing trailing part is I use the code

```
str.substring(0,str.length -2)
```

Is there a better way? I especially dislike using str.length.

**Edit**
I wanted the question to be as short and simple as possible and I supposed that I just overlooked some String method. I try to be more precise.

I need to remove given number of characters from the end of a string. I don't want to care what the characters are and I don't want to introduce a risk of removing more characters.

If the number is larger then string length let's there is an exception (the string should be validated earlier).

I don't have the problem especially with length, but with referencing a variable twice (imagine a function instead of a variable). I also don't like necessity of subtraction but it is only a personal preference.

**VB.NET soution**

The question is taged vb.net so there is vb.net code (should be in a module):

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
Public Shared Function RemoveFromEnd(stringValue As String, removedCharacters As Integer) As String
    Return stringValue.Substring(0, stringValue.Length - removedCharacters)
End Function
```

Comment: what do you mean by `trailing part`?

Comment: In order to remove the last x characters of a string you must know its length.  If you just don't like seeing this in your code then you could write an extension method to hide the calculation.

Comment: @Duane: I mean removing last x characters.

Comment: str.Length - 2 will break if your original string is < 2 characters in length

Comment: @JamesGaunt: try it as answer. It seems you have a good chance.

Comment: @ShanPlourde Let's suppose I know something about string.

Comment: @IvanH what you you mean by "suppose I know something about string"?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you dislike using `str.length`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your concern is simply the aesthetics of what you're looking at, it is trivial to wrap this functionality in an extension method:

```
    public static string RemoveFromEnd(this string stringValue, int removedCharacters)
    {
       return stringValue.Substring(0, stringValue.Length - removedCharacters);
    }
```

So you could then simply use

```
    str.RemoveFromEnd(2);
```

and be done with it.

If you are instead worried about the performance of using string.length due to its reputation for being slow in unmanaged languages, don't be.  Since strings in .Net are immutable, String.Length is set when the string is declared and never changes.  Therefore, referencing String.Length completes in *constant* time (e.g., Big-O(1)) and is very quick.  By contrast, you should instead focus on the Substring call if you're sensitive to performance.  In .Net, Substring completes in *linear* time (e.g., Big-O(n)) where n is the length of your original string.  It is therefore the performance bottleneck in your line of code.  It will become slower with respect to the length of the string.

If you're dealing with very long strings, though, it may not be OK to just swallow that.  To get around something like this you would use a StringBuilder in your extension method instead:

```
    public static string RemoveFromEnd(this string stringValue, int removedCharacters)
    {
        var newString = new StringBuilder(stringValue);
        newString.Length = newString.Length - removedCharacters;
        return newString.ToString();
    }
```

This should be all constant time, but I need to double check Reflector to make sure StringBuilder.Length behaves the way I think it does.  Even if it's linear time, though, it'll be linear with respect to removedCharacters, which is necessarily going to be lower than the length of the original string.  The tradeoff, obviously, is that you have slightly more memory use until the StringBuilder goes out of scope, but that shouldn't be an issue if you wrap it in an extension method that completes really fast.

EDIT: Yes, StringBuilder.Length simply returns String.Length of the string it's keeping track of, so that returns in constant time and the StringBuilder approach to truncation should be as fast as it can reasonably be.

Comment: Interesting. I thought `StringBulider.Length` was a get-only property, but I see that you're correct, it's get/set. It will append a lot of `'\0'` characters if you increase `Length`. I wonder when you will ever want that ...

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen When you're preparing to dump a bunch of stuff into the builder all piecemeal and don't want the thing to constantly reallocate the underlying data structure.  You'd have to use an index variable and some other stuff that I'd argue is generally too complicated and unreadable to be worth it but if performance becomes a big consideration you might just have to rely on the magic of comments.

Comment: When I asked the question I was interested in aesthetics but I appreciate the information about performance too. Do you have some estimation of length for which is better to use StringBuilder?

Comment: @IvanH It's all relative to where you're programming on.  Since string.substring is in linear time there's no tipping point where it mathematically becomes obscene, it's just going to continue going up smoothly the longer your string gets.  Someone who's on relatively modest machinery might have to look at alternatives at only a couple thousand characters, while someone on very beefy hardware might not even think about it until 20k.  But for my part I tend to use StringBuilder any time I need to futz around with something on the file level, like XML file feeds or something.

Comment: If the substring is linear and StringBuilder constant there should be some point where the time is the same and the point is probably independent on hardware (when there is enough of memory).

Comment: In practical terms, linear time with respect to something that is bounded to be small is indistinguishable from constant time.  It's still plenty provable that a constant time algorithm is faster, but in practice it won't matter; 10 nanoseconds is twice as fast as 20 but we can't perceive that.  What is 'small' will depend on what you're running stuff on.  As far as their mathematical intercepts (the point where time is the same), that's Big-O(x) where x = the number of constant time declarations you're making (which is like 5-10 in this case, mostly in StringBuilder.Length's setter).

Comment: The `Substring` version is approximately twice as fast as the `StringBuilder` version in all cases that I tested (strings from 100 to 1,000,000 characters long). This makes sense, because creating the `StringBuilder` requires copying the data from the string, and then copying it again (minus two characters) when `ToString` is called. Also, the time required is proportional to the string length in both cases. That is, both algorithms are O(n). Using `StringBuilder` does not make this "constant time."

Comment: @Jim Out of curiosity what precisely is making it linear time in using the StringBuilder approach?  I came to my conclusion via analysis in Reflector and I'd like to know what I missed.

Comment: @YYY: As I said in my comment, creating a `StringBuilder` from the string requires that the string's contents be copied to a new buffer. Then, after you change the length, calling `ToString()` copies the data again. So you end up copying the data twice. Using `Substring`, you only copy the data once.

Comment: @Jim The copy should be some constant time though, since it's a direct memory-to-memory assignment (it would be bounded by the speed of your RAM).  In something this small the memory is usually already allocated too.  If it turns out that the constant bound is high enough that it overrides the benefit of having it in constant time then that's fine, it's interesting to know.  But if memory assignment is linear with respect to the size of the object in .net then that's something I didn't know and it would be very useful to know that.

Answer (score 5):

Check out this related question:

[Trim string from the end of a string in .NET - why is this missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170909/trim-string-from-end-of-string-in-net-why-is-this-missing)

Since there is no built in method to do this, you'll need to make your own method (preferably an extension method):

```
public static string RemoveCharsFromEnd(this string input, int charactersToRemove) 
{
    if (input.Length > charactersToRemove) 
        return input.substring(0, input.Length - charactersToRemove);
    else
        return "";
}
```

Comment: +1 for dealing with the case where the whole string should be removed.

Comment: This answer is good but the accepted answer is more precise. I especially appreciate the link to the other question (with different accepted answer) which I did not find.

Answer (score 3):

So there does exist a way to remove the first `2` chars of string without using `str.Length`, namely

```
str.Substring(2)
```

and therefore you ask how to do it from the other end? I don't think the framework offers that. You may use

```
str.Remove(str.Length - 2)
```

but that uses `Length`.

Here's an ugly way that uses Linq and has bad performance:

```
new string(str.Reverse().Skip(2).Reverse().ToArray())
```

The ugly idea does not throw exceptions when the string is too short.

Comment: It answered the question +1.  I personally don't see why the question is being up voted but answers are being down voted.

Comment: I voted it up but it is too ugly to be accepted as an asnswer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by 'trailing part'. Do you mean whitespace after the content? So for example:

```
string test = "This is a test string.   "; // But you want "This is a test string."
```

and you want to remove the spaces after? This is possible with the `.Trim()` or `.TrimEnd()` commands. If you do not mean this, please specify what the problem is.

Comment: I need to remove arbitrary characters (not just spaces or specified characters).

Comment: That did not answer the question but you did properly qualify it. Did not deserve a down vote.  +1 to get you even.

Comment: Thanks Blam. I guess it's quite the risk answering unclear/vague questions. I really thought this was the most likely question.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var test = " test";
        // Trim all trailing spaces
        test = test.Trim();
        // Trim only starting trailing spaces
        test = test.TrimStart();
        // Trim only ending trailing spaces
        test = test.TrimEnd();


        var test = "abcTest";
        // Trim all trailing abc
        var toRemove = new char[3];
        toRemove[0] = 'a';
        toRemove[1] = 'b';
        toRemove[2] = 'c';
        test = test.TrimStart(toRemove);
```

You should use the Trim() function to remove the trailing part

Comment: I need to remove arbitrary characters (not just spaces or specified characters).

Comment: Trim, TrimStart and TrimEnd have overloads where you may pass a char[] with the arbitrary characters to remove. Here is the definition: "The string that remains after all occurrences of characters in the trimChars parameter are removed from the start of the current string. If trimChars is null or an empty array, white-space characters are removed instead." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx

Comment: "Arbitrary characters" means that he wants to remove the last two characters, regardless of what they are. Your proposed solution would require that he pass a `char[]` that contains every possible character--all 65,536 of them.

Comment: @JasonDeOliveira Suppose he has a string with twelve digits in it, and he needs a string where the last two digits are removed. Then `TrimEnd` won't help him (even if he gives it a `char[]` with all digits in it).

Comment: @JimMischel Yeah, and then his entire string would be trimmed away :-)

Comment: As with me, you didn't answer the question on IvanH's mind but you did give a good answer to the most likely question. I upvoted you to compensate for the downvote you got. You don't deserve it either.