# How to remove suffix from a word in c#?

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to remove a suffix/verb tense from the words I get and return them to their original state.
For example:
play - playing
watches - watch
stopped - stop
I tried to search some information how to do it but I couldn't find any.

I tried to use Humanizer and OpenNlp but I don't know how it actually works and couldn't find any method I need from them.

```
   public List<string> changeWord(List<string> wordss,string baseUrl)
    {
        string[] wordEnd = {"ing","es", "ies"};
        List<string> tags = getH1AndTitleTags(baseUrl);
        foreach(string tag in tags)
        {
            if (tag.Contains(wordEnd[0]))
            {
                tag.Replace("ing", "");
                tags.Add(tag);
            }
        }
        return tags;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide example and what eventually you have tried

Comment: Its likely too broad (affects other words as well) but you could something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170909/trim-string-from-the-end-of-a-string-in-net-why-is-this-missing

Comment: its not what exactly what I need because I dont know with what the word ends

Comment: If you want a list of only the words with endings (by your definition) removed, you should build a new list and return that, not add to the existing `tags` one.

Comment: I dont need words that i configured it just for the example

Comment: When you replace any "ing", you will mutilate "ingress" - you will need to check that the word actually *ends* on that suffix and only replace *that*. And then there's "ping" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this package: Porter2StemmerStandard. Here is the sample code:

```
using Porter2StemmerStandard;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create a new stemmer
        var stemmer = new EnglishPorter2Stemmer();

        // Stem a word
        string word = "playing";
        var stemmedWord = stemmer.Stem(word);
        Console.WriteLine(stemmedWord.Value); // Output: play

        // Stem another word
        word = "watches";
        stemmedWord = stemmer.Stem(word);
        Console.WriteLine(stemmedWord.Value); // Output: watch

        // Stem a third word
        word = "stopped";
        stemmedWord = stemmer.Stem(word);
        Console.WriteLine(stemmedWord.Value); // Output: stop
    }
}
```